# Relative path wildcards in .jshintignore not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jshint, gulp

I have a web project in a path like this:

```
/vhosts/mysite/
```

And my js files are here:

```
/vhosts/mysite/public/js/
```

When using `gulp-jshint`, I have a `.jshintignore` file here:

```
/vhosts/mysite/.jshintignore
```

`gulpfile.js` looks like this so far:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');

gulp.task('default', function(){
        return gulp.src('./public/js/*.js')
                .pipe(jshint())
                .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));
});
```

I can't get relative wildcard paths to be ignored using `.jshintignore`:

```
bootstrap.min.js    // This works

*.min.js    // This doesn't work

./*.min.js   // This doesn't work either

/vhosts/mysite/public/js/*.min.js    // This works
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*.min.js` will only look in the current directory for `.min.js` files.

You need to write `**/*.min.js` which will recursively look for any `.min.js` files below your working directory.